Could an engineered floor joist be damaged by weight hung by screwed-in eye hook?
Without looking up whether it could take the load or not, I hung an 80 lbs heavy bag from an eye hook screwed into the bottom flange of an engineered floor joist in my unfinished basement. It hung there for about 6 months (only used it several times for a light workout) until I looked up whether it could take the load and then removed the bag with the eye hook still screwed in. How concerned should I be? P.S. I am not a handy person and in some ways want to just reassure myself that I won't have major problems down the road.

concerned about what? ... you did not describe any problem

80# is nothing for load on a floor joist.  floors are typically rated for 40lbs psf live load and 10lbs psf dead load and that is for deflection or rigidity not for failure.  to get some kind of plastic deformation failure in your floor joist you'd have to load it with thousands of pounds and even then it would probably need to be at the center of the span of the joist.  the joists are tied together with cross bridging and the subfloor so they also work as a system.

If the bottom flange isn't  damaged you did no harm and your concern is to remove the hook before someone hits their head on it.

I read that bottom flanges couldn't take a lot of downward pressure and notching them and drilling into them would cause issues.

As long as the bag just hung there, you should be fine.  If you gave it a bunch of whacks, you might start to worry.

There are a whole bunch of punching bag questions on this site already, as well as many asking about hanging loads from ceilings in general. Please search and read them, then revise your post to ask something more clear and specific and provide enough detail for us to answer.

Perhaps most relevant among those: Hanging heavy bag from I-joists and How to hang load from ceiling I-joists behind drywall?

This is my opinion only, but if you are drilling a hole, displacing wood on the bottom side of an engineered framing member in tension, I would not do it to any others. One should not be a concern. If it was in the top, it would have been a different matter. Wood in compression reacts differently.
Should you want to keep the bag hanging there, I would place a 3' piece of 2X12 screwed to the bottom of 3 joists, presuming they are at 16" centers, then screw an eye screw into that, or better yet an eye bolt, since you have access to the top of the 2X12.
